# SQLite query only returning 1 result per argument in WHERE clause

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to query my SQLite DB for all rows that have a particular "city" column.

The following code iterates through a List of cities and creates a WHERE clause.

```
w = PlacesProvider.KEY_CITY + " IN " + "(" + "'" + PlacesSearch.currentCity.get(0) + "'";

for (int i = 1; i < PlacesSearch.currentCity.size(); i++) {
    w = w + ", " + "'" + PlacesSearch.currentCity.get(i) + "'";
}

w = w + ")";

//Result looks like "city IN ('city1', 'city2')"

// Get ContentResolver
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
// Get Cursor
Cursor c = cr.query(PlacesProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, w, null, null);
```

I've also tried this WHERE clause which gives the exact same result.

```
w = PlacesProvider.KEY_CITY + " = " + "'" + PlacesSearch.currentCity.get(0) + "'";
for (int i = 1; i < PlacesSearch.currentCity.size(); i++) {
    w = w + " OR " + PlacesProvider.KEY_CITY + " = " + "'" +  PlacesSearch.currentCity.get(i) + "'";
}

//Result looks like "city = 'city1' OR city = city2 OR city = city3"
```

Then I iterate through the results and use the data:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

//Do some stuff

    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

The problem is that the query only returns 1 row from each city.  If I leave the field null there are plenty of results in each city so I know there are more stored in the DB.

What is wrong here? It's my first time using SQL.

Thanks.

Update:

```
"city IN ('Victoria', 'Saanich', 'Oak Bay')"
"city='Victoria' OR city='Oak Bay' OR city='Saanich'"
```

These are the values of w I've tried.

Update 2:

```
SELECT * FROM coffeeshops WHERE city = 'Victoria' UNION SELECT * FROM coffeeshops WHERE city = 'Oak Bay' UNION SELECT * FROM coffeeshops WHERE city = 'Saanich'
```

I've used rawQuery as suggested and constructed the above statement.  These changes aren't reflected in the code above.  There are no errors when I run it but the result is the same.  I tried using UNION instead and I still get only 1 row for each city.  I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: Have you tried it with a `dbobject`.`rawQuery("SELECT yourthings FROM yourdb WHERE yourwhereclause")` instead of the structured one?  With SQLite I've had the most success with this.

Comment: Try grabbing and posting the generated sql from your code (either through the Log or debugging) - it may help.

Comment: I've updated the post with the actual value of w when I run the application.  It seems good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was with an earlier insert method after all.  Thanks for the comments.  The code above works fine now.  Hopefully someone will find this useful.